# How to reuse .NET projects while allowing obfuscation

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, obfuscation, solidworks

I'm looking for options to share more code between my products. I have about ten products (built in C#) and most of them need a Logging, Licensing and Common project. Right now I copy the projects and rename them, so most code gets duplicated now. I prefer to reuse that code so I can reference a few common packages.

The hard things are:

1. The products run as add-ins within SolidWorks, so all products run in a single process. SolidWorks has issues with running add-ins in a separate appdomain so we can only load each DLL once.
2. We ship the installer to the user, so I obfuscate the projects first. Most classes are marked internal and most projects use the InternalsVisibleTo attribute. Only the classes SolidWorks needs to instantiate are marked public.
3. Users can run multiple products, which may not use the same DLL version. So we need strong-name signing.

Solutions I have considered:

1. Creating NuGet packages for internal use. Great because you can release versions and update each product at its own pace. I would need to mark most classes as public, which makes obfuscation a lot less effective. Certainly for the licensing project.
2. Using git submodules. This would let you reference a shared project. Allows for full obfuscation at build time. But since the project name, the non-obfuscated content and the DLL name would be the same, the obfuscated content will not. This will cause conflicts between non-identical versions.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You should look info about Monorepo estructure that have several advantages compared to multirepo solutions (your case). Basically it consist in having a single repo where you store all you projects and dependencies are resolved by referencing projects. This solution has multiple advantages as i.e: easy to debug, always be referenceing the last version, fast error detection, etc.
Also it's important to have the proper amount of tests to detect posible errors in any solution.

Comment: I don't understand how that helps me reuse modules. Each product already has its own git repo with 4-10 projects in one solution and the projects already reference each other. Now I just copy the module I want to reuse to the git repo of the new product, then rename it to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Why can't you take care of the AppDomain instead? Put as little code into the official add-in DLL as possible, create an AppDomain immediately and let everything else run in the AppDomain.

Comment: I haven't used strong-naming for a long time, but isn't the idea of that exactly that you can load multiple DLLs with the same name and still be able to distinguish them?

Comment: @ThomasWeller We tried using a separate AppDomain, but it exposed all kinds of weird SolidWorks bugs. And yes, strong naming is a requirement, not a problem.